# Javascript .one event equivalent? Need to check when first transform transitionEnd fires

Tags: javascript

Was wondering if there's a javascript `.one` equivalent? Basically I need to detect when my transform fires but only once, at the moment the transitionend event fires twice which is messing up my transitions. I was hoping to use the `event.propertyName` but this just reads 'transform' which doesn't help. Example snippet here:

```
loader.addEventListener("transitionend", function(event) {
    console.log(event); // fires twice
    //if (event.propertyName === 'transform') {
      togglePages(page);
    //}
  }, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one:

```
function one(element, eventName, callback) {
    element.addEventListener(eventName, function handler(event) {          
        element.removeEventListener(eventName, handler);            
        callback(event);
    });
}
```

Now you can do:

```
one(loader, "transitionend", function(event) {
  console.log(event); 
  togglePages(page);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple control variable:

```
var didHappen = false;

loader.addEventListener("transitionend", function(event) {
    if (!didHappen) {
        togglePages(page);
        didHappen = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener).

Example:

```
loader.addEventListener("transitionend",function transition(event) {
    loader.removeEventListener("transitionend", transition, false);
    //if (event.propertyName === 'transform') {
      togglePages(page);
    //}
  }, false);
```

Or

```
var transition =  function (event) {
    loader.removeEventListener("transitionend", transition, false);
    //if (event.propertyName === 'transform') {
      togglePages(page);
    //}
  };
loader.addEventListener("transitionend", , false);
```